# visual basic in powerpoints

Tags: excel, powerpoint, office-interop, vba

I sometimes create macros for excell in visual basic. But I never user it for a PowerPoint. I have a powerpoint with a lot of pictures. The pictures are all in a directory. Sometimes I change the pictures in the directory keeping their original name. Obviously in PowerPoint there is no way to refresh the new versions of the pictures. But I could right click on picture and "change the picture" selecting the same path. Anyway I have too much pictures and I have to change the files often. So I was wondering if there is a way to do with visual basic. I could create a vector with the name of the files in the directory putting the names in the same order that they appear in the ppt. Then create a macro that change again all paths so the pictures will upgrade. I have no idea a about the code I could use. Somebody can help me?

Comment: "Obviously in PowerPoint there is no way to refresh the new versions of the pictures."  Not so.  When you insert the pictures into PPT, click the arrow next to the Insert button and choose to Link the pictures.  Then, if the pictures change, PPT will use the new version whenever you open the PPT file again.  If for some reason that doesn't suit you, say so; there are other ways of doing it with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do this with "macro"
BUT!
you can use `Office Interop` - and code this.
look at this site:
http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/how-to-create-a-powerpoint-presentation-using-c-and-embed-a-picture-to-the-slide/
basically you can write a `.Net` program that do this via Office Interop

hope this helps...

**EDIT:**
Main code part from the link above:

```
string pictureFileName = "C:\\temp\\example.jpg"; 

Application pptApplication = new Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;

// Create the Presentation File
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

// Create new Slide
slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);

// Add title
objText = slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "FPPT.com";
objText.Font.Name = "Arial";
objText.Font.Size = 32;

objText = slide.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "Content goes here\nYou can add text\nItem 3";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape = slide.Shapes[2];
slide.Shapes.AddPicture(pictureFileName,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,shape.Left, shape.Top, shape.Width, shape.Height);

slide.NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This demo is created by FPPT using C# - Download free templates from http://FPPT.com";



pptPresentation.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\fppt.pptx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
//pptPresentation.Close();
//pptApplication.Quit();
```